# Is it smelly to raise an event from within another event?

Tags: c#, events

```
public class Basket
{
    private int _unitCount;

    public int UnitCount
    {
        get { return _unitCount; }
        set
        {
            _unitCount = Math.Max(0, value);
            OnUnitCountChanged(new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler UnitCountChanged;
    public event EventHandler Depleted;

    protected virtual void OnUnitCountChanged(EventArgs args)
    {
        var handler = UnitCountChanged;
        if(handler!=null) { handler(this, args); }
        if(_unitCount == 0) { OnDepleted(new EventArgs()); }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDepleted(EventArgs args)
    {
        var handler = UnitCountChanged;
        if(handler!=null) { handler(this, args); }
    }
}
```

Is there a problem with checking the conditions for Depleted and raising that event if necessary *within the UnitCountChanged* event, or should I be doing both in the UnitCount setter (and anywhere else in a non-trivial example)?

Comment: If it's non-trivial to determine that an item is depleted from the `OnUnitCountChanged` event, I would argue that the `OnDepleted` event is redundant.

Comment: Technically true, but I wanted to minimize the number of places in which I would have to write that exact code, i.e.: deleting the depleted object from its container, presenting the effects in the UI, etc. But I see how this very pared down example would prompt your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I have seen it, I would recommend against it and raise the event in methods that it would occur in, like your `UnitCount` setter.  Since you have the `virtual` access modifier keyword, someone could override the method and if they don't call the base object it wouldn't work as expected.

I'm not a fan of making it more complicated to use my code.

Answer (score 6):

There are times when it may be useful (for example, if you are extending a base class and do not have the ability to override the methods that are raising the events), but in general, I'd recommend against it.

In this case, I'd say it's better to raise both events in the `UnitCount` setter:

```
public int UnitCount
{
    get { return _unitCount; }
    set
    {
        _unitCount = value;
        OnUnitCountChanged(new EventArgs());
        if(_unitCount == 0) { OnDepleted(new EventArgs()); }
    }
}
```